# Expressions vs computed properties in templates in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

What is better to use in templates: expressions or computed properties?

Ex:

```
<span :class="'static_part' + dynamic_part"></span>
...
data: {
    dynamic_part: 'xxx',
}
```

or

```
<span :class="span_class"></span>
...
data: {
    dynamic_part: 'xxx',
},
computed: {
    span_class() {
        return 'static_part' + dynamic_part;
    }
}
```

1-st way is smaller and easier to understand. But what about performance?

Comment: In this instance I'd say: whichever one you prefer and feel is easiest to maintain. The performance of calling a function and concatenating two strings is orders of magnitude smaller than any real bottleneck that will impact perceived performance by the user. If this gets rendered 1000s of times on a page or incredibly frequently then this might be worth revisiting. Until then: whatever you prefer and is easiest to maintain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to official [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html)

> In-template expressions are very convenient, but they are meant for simple operations. Putting too much logic in your templates can make them bloated and hard to maintain

and

> Instead of a computed property, we can define the same function as a method. For the end result, the two approaches are indeed exactly the same. However, the difference is that **computed properties are cached based on their reactive dependencies**

I see that using computed property could also separate the logic from the content and help other who will read your code that this properties are calculated and based on other ones